# QueueInsertItemsRequest sender example on ChromeCast SDK

Tags: web, chromecast

I'm trying to write a chromecast sender (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_sender/) in my web app.

I haven't tried creating a custom receiver yet. I'm hoping I can just allow the default receiver to manage the queue by using loadMedia [1], LoadRequest [2], and QueueInsertItemsRequest [3] on the sender side.

However, I can't figure out the right way to use QueueInsertItemsRequest - is it via sendMessage() [4] ?  If so, what namespace do I use?

[1] https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_sender/cast.framework.CastSession#loadMedia
[2] https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_sender/chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest
[3] https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_sender/chrome.cast.media.QueueInsertItemsRequest
[4] https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_sender/cast.framework.CastSession#sendMessage